# ChartJS (Radar) - Set base tick position for "0" value

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Using chart.js ([v3.7.0](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.7.0/))

Set up a **Radar** chart using multiple datasets that include `0` values (and needs to be kept as `0` for tooltip & data purposes).

Trying to find a way to set/include a drawn tick marker for `0` values on the chart that do not all collide at the center of the graph (`0` is a viable data value itself for this project).

`beginAtZero` option has no effect whatsoever on the initial tick display position.

| [image: Current Chart Display] | [image: Desired Chart Display] |
| --- | --- |

Is this what's supposed to happen with the `beginAtZero` option, and there's been some sort of regression? If not, is this even possible with chart.js?

**Options:**

```js
options = {
    scales: {
      r: {
        min: 0,
        max: 99,
        beginAtZero: true,
        angleLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          display: false,
          stepSize: 33.333
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Sample Data:**

```js
data = {
    labels: [ 'Field 1', 'Field 2', 'Field 3', 'Field 4', 'Field 5', 'Field 6' ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        data: [ 10, 99, 0, 76, 0, 0 ],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 213, 117, 0.6)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 213, 117)',
        fill: true
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        data: [ 99, 35, 0, 0, 54, 0 ],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        fill: true
      }
    ],
  }
```

**Tried:**

[Negative Min Values] - When attempting to use a negative value for `min`, it leaves some sort of masking on the pathing fills. Used in combination with some other visual property settings, but nothing seemed to resolve. **(RESOLVED - See below)**

[image: Negative Min Chart]

Thanks in advance!

## **[PERSONAL SOLUTION]**

In combination with [@LeeLenalee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8682983/leelenalee)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70679913/10653420), I was able to identify my own personal issue with the "masking" from the paths. Using negative `min` value does indeed properly offset the starting value of the paths. Furthermore, if a dataset has `fill: true`, it apparently also masks any pathing fills drawn outside the boundaries of the data (in this case, a negative `min` value). After removing this property from each dataset, the paths fill correctly.

```js
data = {
    labels: [ 'Field 1', 'Field 2', 'Field 3', 'Field 4', 'Field 5', 'Field 6' ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        data: [ 10, 99, 0, 76, 0, 0 ],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 213, 117, 0.6)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 213, 117)',
        // -- fill: true
      }
    ],
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easyest way to achieve this is by setting your min to the negative of your stepSize like so:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        data: [10, 99, 0, 76, 0, 0],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        data: [99, 35, 0, 0, 54, 0],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      r: {
        min: -33.333,
        max: 99,
        beginAtZero: true,
        angleLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          display: false,
          stepSize: 33.333
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Lee - this was actually one of the (several) methods I tried. While it heads in the right direction, there seems to be some sort of masking that happens on the paths for this method. Updated question include a screen.

Comment: I was able to review your answer/settings a bit more thoroughly - helped me identify and resolve the "masking" issue I was facing. Personal, one-off problem though; updated initial question with the resolution. Thanks for your help!